# Design Bug - CSS? IE10? - I'm stuck

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Here's a Design I've started.  Fairly simple.

It's a Container Div with 3 main Div's  Header, Content, Footer.

Header, Content, Footer have background-images sliced from image.

It shows correctly in FF (all), Chrome (all), Android, Safari, IE >6 and <= 9 and IE 11

Only in "IE10" the footer background-image seems to disappear or something?

The header and the footer are pretty much identical in styling etc. and no

probs with header.

Validates, w3c.

I've tried everything I can think of......  every element attribute I can think of. Even re-saved

footer slice image in various formats.

The only way I can get to show is by putting IE into quirks mode. I don't want

to do that. emulating other IE modes doesn't work either until I get to quirks mode.

I must be missing something?

Here's an image of the issue...

http://inkspotpens.net/ie-prob-1.jpg

Also a live link to the R&D server

http://www.inkspotpens.net

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just attempted to view your site in IE10 (through IE11's compatability mode) and the footer loaded fine...

Comment: Since the content is floated in your footer, try using a clearfix to make sure the browser interprets the height of the element.

Comment: @ZackHuber Using the IE 10 Document Mode in IE 11 is not the same as viewing the site in IE 10. [IE doesn't have an emulation feature](http://sampsonblog.com/768/ie-doesnt-have-an-emulation-feature).

Comment: @ZackHuber - yes, the F12 tools IE10 compat in IE11 do not show the issue.

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness tried to apply the clear fix to the floats parent container (footer)                                      .clear:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}